# Printing exceptions thrown by thread-pool threads, Java's default behavior

Tags: java, concurrency

I asked this question: [Printing the stack trace from a newly created thread when an unchecked exception is thrown in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817420/printing-the-stack-trace-from-a-newly-created-thread-when-an-unchecked-exception)

And got this in a reply by the user Gray: "By default there is nothing that prints the exceptions thrown by thread-pool threads."

I'd like to know the reason why that is. It seems confusing to me to have a thread-pool thread throw an unchecked exception and stop working without printing any errors by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if it printed it, another developer would ask why it cripples the output of the program with unwanted stack traces, and reduces the throughput drastically by writing the stack traces to a synchronized PrintStream. If you want the exceptions to be printed, then print them by yourself. Nothing prevents you from doing it.

The answer you got shows how to do that. You could also wrap all your runnables with another runnable that catches the runtime exceptions, prints them when they are thrown, and rethrow them.

Comment: So the problem with printing stack traces from thread-pool threads is that PrintStream is synchronized and, therefore, it performs much worse in this situation? I'm trying to understand why is it so bad to print those from thread-pool threads but it's OK to do so in the main thread.

Comment: It's just that doing it by default would annoy many people, and would reduce the performance. If you want traces, add traces.

Answer (score 2):

One would have to alter the program, for instance a Thread has a [set(Default)UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).
With AOP one could achieve such a thing.